# Strange behaviour with cookies

Tags: nuxtjs3

I am trying to debug an application where cookies seem to be lagging: just after setting the cookie with `useCookie`, I can't always read the cookie: *sometimes* it is only sent to the server after reading it once. What am I doing wrong?

Here is an extremely simple example demonstrating the behaviour (you need `@pinia/nuxt`):

```ts
// app.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="setcookie">setcookie</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">

import { useMyUserStore } from "~/stores/user"

const store = useMyUserStore()

async function setcookie() {
    const before  = await $fetch('/api/getcookie')
    console.log('cookie before setToken=',before);
    store.setToken('test')
    const first = await $fetch('/api/getcookie')
    console.log('cookie first fetch=',first);
    const second = await $fetch('/api/getcookie')
    console.log('cookie second fetch=',second);
}
</script>
```

```ts
// /stores/user.ts
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useMyUserStore = defineStore('user', () => {

    const token = useCookie('MyCookie', { sameSite: 'lax' })

    function setToken(t?:string) { token.value = t }

    return { token, setToken }
})
```

```ts
// /server/api/getcookie.ts
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
    const cookie = parseCookies(event)
    return cookie
})
```

Result is this (consistently in `Chromium`, more random in `Firefox`):

```
cookie before setToken= {}
cookie first fetch= {}
cookie second fetch= {MyCookie: 'test'}
```

In fact, for the first `$fetch` after setting the cookie, any endpoint will do. I created this one and the behaviour is the same:

```ts
// /server/api/noop.ts
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  return
})
```

So my plan is to call that `noop` endpoint just to make sure the cookie is sent afterwards. A bit ridiculous IMO